# Fix the cycle of adding a number to the listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Help me fix - Add the number 20 to each row of the "Total" column -- Screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OOye.png

```
for (int itt = 1; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
{
        int Totall = 20;
        listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Add(Totall);
}
```

Comment: ListView uses strings, so you'll need int.Parse() to read the string back and int.ToString() to generate the updated value.  Do always strongly favor separating the model from the view so these kind of hacks are not necessary.

Comment: You can write the code ? 
i just have no idea

Answer (score 1):

If by add you mean mathematical addition use this :

```
        for (int itt = 1; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
        {
            int Totall = 20;
            listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Text = (int.Parse(listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Text) + Totall).ToString();
        }
```

if you want to just add "20" to the end of the line then use this:

```
        for (int itt = 1; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
        {
            int Totall = 20;
            listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Text = listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Text + Totall;
        }
```

Comment: The reference to the object does not indicate an instance of the object.